# Cannot cast selector in LINQ Select to correct type

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to have a dynamic Retrieve function where I could pass in a .Select() selector of a custom type.

```
public IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking> RetrieveBookingsForWorkOrder(Guid workOrderId, Expression<Func<BookableResourceBooking, dynamic>> selector)
    {
        return (IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking>)
            CrmServiceContext.BookableResourceBookingSet
            .Where(x => x.msdyn_WorkOrder.Id == workOrderId)
            .Select(selector);
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
.RetrieveBookingsForWorkOrder(
  workOrderId,
  x => new BookableResourceBooking() { Id = x.Id, StartTime = x.StartTime, EndTime = x.EndTime })
```

This throws an error:

> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.Query`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GiGA.Common.Crm.BookableResourceBooking]'.

If I put the selector there manually, it works:

```
.Select(x => new BookableResourceBooking() { Id = x.Id, StartTime = x.StartTime, EndTime = x.EndTime }); // this is fine
```

How should I call the function with the selector in the parameter?

Comment: So, why parameter  returns `dynamic`?

Comment: you may use generic method (not whole class)`IEnumerable<T> RetrieveBookingsForWorkOrder<T>(Guid workOrderId, Expression<Func<BookableResourceBooking, T>> selector)` if you wana be able to return different types...

Comment: with generics there will be no casting at all ... it will be determined on Expression<Func<IN, OUT>> OUT parameter  ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/DvkXI2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `dynamic` is just `object` as far as the compiled IL is concerned. It just tells the compiler not to throw errors on methods that aren't found.

So this code:

```
public IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking> RetrieveBookingsForWorkOrder(
    Guid workOrderId, Expression<Func<BookableResourceBooking, dynamic>> selector)
{
    return (IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking>)
        CrmServiceContext.BookableResourceBookingSet
        .Where(x => x.msdyn_WorkOrder.Id == workOrderId)
        .Select(selector);
}
```

Is the same as this:

```
public IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking> RetrieveBookingsForWorkOrder(
    Guid workOrderId, Expression<Func<BookableResourceBooking, object>> selector)
{
    return (IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking>)
        CrmServiceContext.BookableResourceBookingSet
        .Where(x => x.msdyn_WorkOrder.Id == workOrderId)
        .Select(selector);
}
```

So the `.Select(selector)` is returning an `IEnumerable<object>` and you're trying to cast it to `(IEnumerable<BookableResourceBooking>)`.

The question is why is `selector` defined this way?

Comment: TIL the second param "dynamic" is the return type and I should just swap it for my type. Thank you!